# What, if anything, should we do about these D&D 5e multiclass spellcasting questions about spell slots?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates, dnd-5e

Currently the following question exists

- [If I multiclass into 2 or more spellcasting classes, how do I determine my known/prepared spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151000)

All of the following questions are currently marked as duplicates of the above one:

- [Can you cast a 9th level spell if your multiclass spell slots have 9th level spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68604)
- [At level up, can a sorcerer learn spells of a level granted by slots he has from any class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91430)
- [Can multiclass druids prepare & cast Druid spells of any level that they have a spell slot for?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100336)
- [When Multi-classing Paladin with Sorcerer, could I Prepare Paladin Spells at my Sorcerer Spell Level (5th level spells max)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106653)
- [Sorcerer Multiclass learning spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117610)
- [When multiclassing a Cleric/Wizard, can I prepare wizard spells from the cleric list that the wiz could learn but didn't?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123333)
- [Land Druid/Cleric Multiclass interaction with spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134848)
- [How does learning spells work when leveling a multiclass character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142715)
- [How many spells does my Bard 6/Wizard 1 know?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150960)
- [Arcane Trickster(9)/Wizard(2) Multiclass Unlocked Spell Levels](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158818)
- [Arcane Trickster Multiclass - Spell Preparation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102008)
- [Does my multiclassed Eldritch Knight fighter/War wizard now have to prepare his spells as an Eldritch Knight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150759)
- [Cantrips for each multi-class class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59158)
- [5e multi-classing with a wizard level 1 and a druid level 1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56531)
- [As a Bard multi-classing into Warlock, what spells do I get?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147297)

And then there are the following questions about spell *slots* which the very first question **does not cover**:

- [How do spell slots and preparation work when multi-classing between cleric and bard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84814)
- [Excessively multiclassed character - how many spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115117)
- [How many spell slots does a multiclassed Cleric (4 levels)/Fighter (Eldritch Knight) (1 level) have?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106905)
- [For multiclassed warlock/clerics, do your spell slots from the two classes stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136860)
- [What spell slots should I have with Paladin 7 / Sorcerer 7?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124622)
- [How many spell slots should a Fighter 11/Ranger 9 have?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145196)
- [How many spell slots should my level 1 wizard/level 1 fighter have?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144594)
- [How are spell slots for an Eldritch Knight fighter 3/Arcane Trickster rogue 3 determined?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160162)

Should something be done regarding all these questions about spell slots for multi-classed spellcasters? Perhaps a general question should be made to address spell *slots* like the one that addresses spells known/prepared?

---

There are even some other related questions about spell slots but are distinct from "How many spell slots do I have?" in one way or another. Thus these may be different enough that anything that happens to the previously mentioned questions wouldn't apply to these:

- [Multiclass Spellcaster: Do the involved classes share the same pool of spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123731)
- [Multiclass Warlock/Sorcerer: How do spell slots recover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45750)
- [What are the effects of Pact Magic and Spellcasting being stacked on the same character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137303)

Comment: Previous discussion on this: [Multiclassing mayhem: should all these questions be duplicates of this question about wizards' spellbooks?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8717/52137)

Comment: Just to clarify my reasoning for not closing others, from that previous meta: "I also went ahead and updated some of the old questions that had been incorrectly marked as a duplicate of the wizard question to point to my new question instead - though I didn't go searching for any others (if at least to avoid flooding the front page all at once)." It's worth addressing in this meta, though.

Comment: (As for spell slots, I think it would be best to make it a separate mainsite question from my known/prepared spells one if that's what people decide, as it is a mostly separate question.)

Comment: To quote Aerys Targaryen - “burn them all.”  Oh, wait, not a tag question.  Sorry. :)

Comment: Wow. Maybe someone should hop on the Twitter and show the game's designers this question. I mean, if there are *that* many questions about this, somebody should let the designers know folks are struggling with their rules. Really, just to be kind to all the folks *don't* visit here.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: They're pretty clearly explained in the same chapter and section as the rest of the multiclassing rules... I don't know what WotC can really do about people not reading the relevant part of the rules before asking a question :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Make a generalized question with a canonical answer, then link all new questions of this type to it.

I think that this is typically what's done about these sorts of things, and evidently small variations of this question keep getting asked regarding different class/level combinations - so I'd suggest to make a single generalized version of this question like "How do spellcasting slots work with a multiclassed character in DnD 5e" and self-answer it with a canonical answer discussing how multiclassing spell slots work for a character in DnD 5e. That way, we can close any new questions of this type as duplicates while leaving the old ones alone unless someone bumps them to the front page.

Comment: This has been done: "[How do I determine how many spell slots I have when multiclassing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167040)" though if you feel there are things missing from that Q/A feel free to explain