# Are any of these questions about the type of additional damage in D&D 5e duplicates?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, duplicates

The following are all related or relatively similar questions about effects that deal damage without specifying a type being combined with effects that deal multiple types of damage at once:

- [Can I choose which damage type my Sneak Attack does if my weapon does multiple types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103132)
- [When a ranged attack deals multiple damage types, can I choose what damage type my Sharpshooter bonus gives?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178020)
- [Can a Barbarian choose which weapon die to add for his Brutal Critical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127429)
- [If the attack or spell that the goblin's Fury of the Small trait is applied to deals multiple types of damage, what type is the extra damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116731)
- [Can a Zealot Barbarian apply Radiant rage damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/172777)

Are any of these duplicates of each other? Worth noting, the second was recently closed as a duplicate of the first.

Comment: Semi-related FAQ: [If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7523/33569) (Though the ways in which this is different to that case is sort of grounds for the answer I'm in the process of writing here.)

Answer (score 6):

### No; some of them might have the same answer, but the questions are about different specific features.

[doppelgreener's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7524/33569) to the linked Q&A [If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7523/33569) says:

> We close Question A as a duplicate of Question B only when **all** of
> the following is true:
>
> - It's the same question, or Question A is already covered
>   **obviously** as a subset of Question B. Obvious here means I can
>   tell at a glance it's there.
> - Question B has an **obvious** answer to Question A. Obvious here
>   means I get a straightforward answer without hard searching — a
>   couple of sentences buried in the middle of a post, or an answer
>   which only sort of implies an answer to Question A, doesn't count as
>   obvious.
> - There is not some strong compelling reason to covering Question A
>   alone, separately from Question B. (If the above bullet points are
>   met this rarely happens.)
>
> The idea here is it's the same question with an obvious answer.
> Someone redirected from Question A to B can see obviously why they
> were redirected and find a satisfactory answer.

In the case of the questions you're asking about, they're about different specific features/cases. They might have the same answer, but they're not quite the same question. As such, they're not actually duplicates of one another.

If there is a general rule in D&D 5e that addresses all the specific variants of this issue, it might make sense to have a canonical Q&A that addresses that general case, and close the others as duplicates of it, as was done in the following case: [What, if anything, should we do about these D&D 5e multiclass spellcasting questions about spell slots?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9624/33569)

However, in this case, there is no such general rule. In fact, several of the Q&As you linked rely on the wording of the specific feature in question; some of them note that there is no such general rule on this matter (and thus have to rely on material from outside the rules to support resolving the issue a certain way). As such, even a canonical Q&A for the general case of "What damage type does extra damage do when it's not specified?" would probably not be a good fit here.

Comment: I would also like to add that the question about the Zealot Barbarian actually has a different answer as well.

Comment: @Weasemunk: Yep! That's the main one I was thinking of when I said "several of the Q&As you linked rely on the wording of the specific feature in question".